# Trying to get my radio buttons to line up

Tags: javascript, html, css

Alright so I'm doing a freecodecamp project of a survey. The codepen that

they want your survey to function like is this

https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/pen/VPaoNP. I currently have mine looking

like https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qvQLZx.

my css

```
#title {
  text-align:center;
}
#description {
  text-align:center
}

#survey-form {
  text-align:center;
}
.leftsidequestions {
  display:inline-block
  margin:auto;
  text-align:right;
}
#number {
  width:9%;
}
```

My problem right now is that I want

my radio buttons lined up like they do in their codepen. Also it wouldnt be

bad if I could figure out how to line up my other questions like theirs. They

have the text to the left and then the buttons/boxes to the right with a

divide in the middle but I can't figure out how to do this.

So far I've tried vertically aligning them and and display blocking and

inlineblocking them.

Comment: google block vs inline

Comment: It looks like they have the css code in their pen

Answer (score 0):

Do like this yourinputs will be in one column check below example.

```
<script src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js"></script>
<div id="main">
<h1 id="title">Survey Form</h1>
<p id="description">Favourite Wu-Tang Things</p>

  <div class="leftsidequestions">
      <form id="survey-form">
       <label id="name-label" for="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="name" id="name" required placeholder="Name"><br>
      <br>
        <label id="email-label" for="email">Email:</label> 
        <input type="email" id="email" required  placeholder="Email"><br>
      <br>
        <label id="number-label" for="age">&ensp; Age: </label>
        <input type="number" id="number" min="1" max="100"  placeholder="Age"><br><br>
        Favourite Wu-Tang Album: 
        <select id="dropdown">
        <option value="1">Enter the Wu-Tang (36 Chambers)</option>
        <option value="2">Wu-Tang Forever</option>
        <option value="3">The W</option>
        <option value="4">Iron Flag</option>
        <option value="5">8 Diagrams</option>
        <option value="6">A Better Tomorrow</option>
        <option value="7">Once Upon a Time in Shaolin</option>
        </select><br><br>
        Favourite Member<br>
        <div class="inputs"><input type="radio" name="member" value"rza">Rza
        <br><input type="radio" name="member" value"gza">Gza
        <br><input type="radio" name="member" value"odb">Ol Dirty Bastard
        <br><input type="radio" name="member" value"Methodman">Method-Man<br>
        <input type="radio" name="member" value"Raekwon">Raekwon
        <br><input type="radio" name="member" value"U-God">U-God
        <br><input type="radio" name="member" value"Masta">Masta Killa
        <br><input type="radio" name="member" value"Ghostface">Ghostface Killah
        </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

first add one div with class name "inputs" and wrap your inputs inside this. and add this css class

```
body

#title {
  text-align:center;
}
#description {
  text-align:center
}

#survey-form {
  text-align:center;
}
.leftsidequestions {
  display:inline-block
  margin:auto;
  text-align:right;
}
#number {
  width:9%;
}

.inputs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto; 
}
```

and see it then in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Following their example, for **every** line they wrapped content on the left and right each in div elements that they set to `inline-block`. Like this:

```css
.left,
.right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
}

.left {
  text-align: right;
}

.right {
  text-align: left;
}

input {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <label id="name-label" for="name">Name:</label>
 </div>
 <div class="right">
   <input type="name" id="name" required placeholder="Name" />
</div>

<div class="left">
  <label id="email-label" for="email">Email:</label>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <input type="email" id="email" required placeholder="Email" />
</div>
```